# Writing new column to CSV

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm trying to write some new data in a CSV and have been able to accomplish what I need to, but not as gracefully as I was hoping and am wondering if someone here had any suggestions on cleaning up my code.

The goal is to take a CSV with a long list of 6-digit numbers under the header "Code", create a new column called "DivisionCode" and assign only the first 2-digits of the "Code" field to that new column.

Here's what I have currently:

```
$Importcsv = import-csv C:\test.csv 

# This takes the named CSV and adds the column "DivisionCode" to the end then
# writes back to the same CSV
$Importcsv | Select-Object *,@{Name='DivisionCode';Expression={''}} |
  Export-Csv C:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation

$Importcsv = import-csv C:\test.csv

foreach ($Number in $Importcsv) {
  $Code = $Number.Code
  $DivisionCode = $Code -replace ".{4}$"
  if ($Number.DivisionCode -like "") {
    $Number.DivisionCode = $DivisionCode
  }
}

$Importcsv | Export-Csv c:\RESONE\test2.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

When I run that as a single script the end result is what I want, but it throws out an error for every row. From what I can tell it's repeatedly trying to create the new column? which doesn't make sense to me since the column creation is outside the ForEach loop? The error it throws is as follows:

```
Select-Object : Property cannot be processed because property "DivisionCode" already
exists.
At C:\Trim2.ps1:4 char:30
+  $Importcsv | Select-Object <<<<  *,@{Name='DivisionCode';Expression={''}} | Export-Csv C:\test.csv
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (@{FirstName=Mad... DivisionCode=}:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AlreadyExistingUserSpecifiedPropertyNoExpand,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand
```

If I place the `Select-Object` portion in its own script, run it first, then run the rest in a second script, it all runs flawlessly but obviously that's not as efficient as it could be.

In addition to that I'm guessing that I'm also overlooking a way to write the data I want to the column at the same time I'm creating the column but I couldn't quite figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message the CSV already has a column `DivisionCode` when you first import it. Add `-Exclude DivisionCode` to the `Select-Object` to get it replaced. Besides, you don't need the repeated import/export. Do everything in one go:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\test.csv' |
  Select-Object *,@{n='DivisionCode';e={$_.Code -replace '.{4}$'}} -Exclude DivisionCode |
  Export-Csv 'C:\RESONE\test2.csv' -NoType -Encoding Ascii
```

Comment: Hmm, it's possible I had already run the code that added the new column once when I had it throw out the errors, that would definitely explain it. This is going to be a script that runs on recurring new versions of the csv that won't have the column to start.

The `e={$_.Code -replace '.{4}$'}` is the part I didn't know how to do. I'll try to study up on `Select-Object` formatting to understand how that works.

Am I correct in understanding the `-Exclude DivisionCode` would only be necessary if the column already existed (which I know it won't?)

Comment: `-Exclude` excludes a property if it exists, otherwise it does nothing.

Comment: Roger that. I tried doing it all in one go as you suggested, omitting the `-Exclude` portion and it worked perfectly; I must have already had the column on my test when I got that slew of errors. Thanks for the help! This was my first foray into PowerShell so I knew there were things I was overlooking.